# Shouldn't Excel support passing off-sheet cell range references to functions?

Tags: excel, vba

You would think so but this fails with a 1004 error

```
Rem This macro is running on sheet2

Dim avg As double

Names.Add Name:="sheet1Avg", RefersTo:="sheet1!$C$2:$C$24"
avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(range("sheet1Avg"))
```

So does this:

```
avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(range("sheet1!$C$2:$C$24))
```

I would hate to have to copy `C2:C24` to the active sheet every time I wanted to use a math function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you actually need this twisted logic, but if you actually do, fix your `RefersTo`:

```
Names.Add Name:="sheet1Avg", RefersTo:="=sheet1!$C$2:$C$24"
```

and change the way you reference the created range - you cannot dereference it with `Range` because it is supposed to return a range on its parent sheet, not on any other sheet:

```
avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Names("sheet1Avg").RefersToRange)
```

---

Otherwise store your range references in local variables of type `Range` and only use named ranges when you wouldn't need to define them at runtime.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you. I find it appalling, though, that something as simple and commonplace as passing the range of cells on an addressable worksheet to a function requires so much Excel expertise to pull off-- indeed in this case, requiring a worldwide teleconference on stackoverflow to determine the syntax of the calling parameter. A great example of the woeful inadequacies of this language and a great business opportunity for someone to do it right.

Comment: @bitdigester Passing a range of cells to a function is easy. `Dim r As Range`, `Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C24")`, then `avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(r)`. Names is for other things, e.g. when you pre-setup the worksheet with named ranges once and then refer to them from your code - but even then the names generally refer to ranges on their own sheet. Or you can make a [global name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2176154/11683) instead of a local one you are using, that would make your `range("sheet1Avg")` work too.

Answer (score 0):

GSerg already explained it very well so take his answer.
Below is just another way of getting your *Average* using the `Evaluate` function.

```
avg = Evaluate("AVERAGE(" & Split(Names(1).RefersTo, "=")(1) & ")")
```

If you created the `Name` correctly as what GSerg pointed out (adding `=` upfront your address) above will work as you expect it returning the average of the address you specify.

Another way is to be explicit in assigning the name. Instead of setting the scope in *Sheet2*, set it in *Workbook*. Something like:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="sheet1Avg2", RefersTo:="=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$24"
```

Then you need to explicitly call it as well like this:

```
avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Sheet1.Range("sheet1Avg2"))
```

where **Sheet1** is the *Sheet Codename*. HTH and not confuse you.

Comment: That didn't work. But thanks for the help. Sheet1 code name was not recognized as an object -- just one of the many many ways of doing things Excel VBA most of which result in failure.

Comment: @bitdigester When used in a range address, the sheet name is the sheet label, as visible to the user. When used directly from code, sheet name is the actual sheet name, not visible to the user and independent from the sheet label. These names you see in the properties pane in the code editor. Apparently you have a sheet with label `Sheet1` and some other actual name. Either use the actual name in the `Average(Sheet1.Range())` or replace that with `Average(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range())`.

Comment: @bitdigester yes it will differ depending on what sheet you're working on or you wish to work on. You can see that in the project window. By default when you open a new workbook in excel, it contains 3 sheets with names sheet1 to sheet3. Their code names are the same. To get the codename using your sheet name you can use your immediate window and type this `?Sheets("Sheetname").Codename`. Or you can do what @GSerg suggest in his comment.