# "With ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item("BBTMembers")" produces 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

After modifying the contents of a range, I loop through it to find out how many rows are present (Counter) then resize the range.  This works for one range but not another.

The code below is a clip from a test Sub that works for the first three lines.  Line four produces Run-time error '1004'.

```
...
With ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item("Namelist")
.RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Resize(Counter / 2, 4)
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item("BBTMembers") 'Run-time error '1004':
                                             'Application-defined or.... 
.RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Resize(Counter / 2, 4)
Range("BBTMembers2") = Range("BBTMembers").Resize(Counter, 4)
End With
...
```

Ranges are defined as Variant and initialized as (0 To 2, 0 To 100).  I am baffled as to why one works and the other doesn't.  I have tried changing the spelling of BBTMembers among other things.

Comment: Open the [name manager](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4) and see what it shows for the name `BBTMembers`.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding "Worksheets("Sheet2")."

Comment: That means the name was [local](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2176154/11683).