# Named range giving Error 1004 'Method 'Range' Of Object 'Worksheet' Failed'

Tags: excel, vba

This code was working just fine, but I did a bunch of other code that manipulates and reads the same area of the sheet and now this section does not work.

I have tried a bunch of stuff with syntax but none worked. It may be that I need to resize my array but since im setting it equal to a range I didnt think that I had to. Also It says the problem is the range but I dont know. I would rather not have to resize as its taking from a larger table whose line items will be dynamic but I can do that and make it dynamic if I need to. I did try deleting the range and renaming it and it did not work.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

      Dim codes()
      Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        codes = ws.Range("cCodes")         

         CostCode1.List = codes     ''these are combo boxes                        
         CostCode2.List = codes
         CostCode3.List = codes
         CostCode4.List = codes
         CostCode5.List = codes
         CostCode6.List = codes

'' ADD UNITS

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA worksheet.names vs worksheet.range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2175962/11683)

Comment: I dont have a sheet with the name codes or cCodes but I do have another range named codes I believe I will try that

Comment: no luck with that

Comment: It is part of a table that will be dynamic so I need it to refer to a range that references the tables first three columns

Comment: @FAB Is there a way for me to directly reference the three columns of the table that I want to set to the array

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to declare the sheet for the named range.
named ranges are stored as an external address including the sheet's Name.

```
codes = Range("cCodes")
```

should be sufficient.

Comment: Unqualified `Range`, when used outside of a sheet's code module, always resolves to `ActiveSheet.Range`. It is [never advised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17733541/11683) to use that.

Comment: @ChrisLafky If this solved it for you, then your named range was on another sheet as opposed to `Sheet1`, and you should have used that sheet instead to qualify the `.Range` call.

Comment: @GSerg how would you do this then? I need the reference to go to the table so I have to use some sort of range I think unless I can directly call the table columns

Comment: @ChrisLafky You had `Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")` and `ws.Range("cCodes")`. If removing the `ws.` fixed it for you, then it must have been some other sheet that has the `cCodes` range. So you would have `Set ws = Worksheets("Other sheet")`.

Comment: It worked last night for some reason but will not work now. I checked the sheet its name is from sheet1 I will try deleting and recreating the range

Comment: by making it a workbook level name and getting rid of the ws. that fixed it

Comment: Now this other piece of code is having that same problem with error 1004 I must be doing something wrong with my named ranges - For Each desc In Range("Description")           With calcs                                                                                                           
   If Me.CostCode1.Value = desc.Value Then
     desc.Offset(, 22).Select

Comment: it is giving me an error because the range reads a value so the offset is not working

Comment: @GSerg If you use this with any other ActiveSheet, `?Range("Table1").Worksheet.Name` will return the sheet name of where the named range is. Obviously that's not the case for normal ranges, but with this particular case I agree with horst, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @FAB You are correct to a degree. `Range("Table1")` will succeed even when a wrong sheet is the `ActiveSheet`, provided that the name in question is a [workbook level name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2176154/11683) (which e.g. Table's names are). However this only pushes the problem one step further: instead of giving error 1004 when a wrong sheet is active, it will give error 1004 when a wrong workbook is active (or worse, will pick up the Table1 range from that other workbook in case where it has one, potentially ruining it). So I would argue one should always qualify their `Range` calls.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that @GSerg. I was just running some tests with 2 open workbooks and named ranges with same name, and arrived to the same conclusion. I'm still trying to figure out how to qualify the named range over a different workbook, but that's a different subject.

Comment: @FAB You don't need to qualify named range over a different workbook, you need to protect yourself from depending on [which book is active](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683). That is, you qualify the `Range` call with your own workbook's sheet object, and that will always work regardless of the active workbook.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the error comes because you don't have the named range `"cCodes"`).

Go to **Formulas** -> **Name Manager** and check your names. Alternatively, use a range directly in the code, i.e.: `codes = ws.Range("A1:A100")`

To answer your question in the comment:

> Is there a way for me to directly reference the three columns of the table that I want to set to the array

Here are a few ways to manipulate the range from your table into the array (specific rows/columns), and back on the sheet (see comments in code). Hope this helps.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim arrData As Variant

    With Range("Table1") 'this is only the content of the table, does not include the headers
        Set rngData = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3)) 'Set the range starting at cell row 1, col 1 - until total number of rows in table, col 3
        'Set rngData = rngData.Offset(-1).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1) 'if you want to include headers as well
        Debug.Print rngData.Address
    End With

    arrData = rngData 'allocate the data from the range to the array

    rngData.Offset(0, Range("Table1").Columns.Count + 1) = arrData 'put the array back on the sheet, 1 column to the right of the table

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("N1").Resize(UBound(arrData), UBound(arrData, 2)) = arrData 'put the array back on the sheet in a specific range

End Sub
```