# Run-time error 1004 when getting location of named ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that outputs the location of all referenced ranges in a specified workbook. Things were working fine for smaller workbooks, but I'm not getting an error on a more complicated workbook. Excel version: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.

The error is:

Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Code is below, with comment of error location:

```
Sub returnNamedRanges()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim file As String
Dim i As Integer
    
'Get location of file to be parsed
file = "C:\location\of\file.xlsm"
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(file)

i = 1
For Each nm In wkb.Names
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("outputSheet").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Range(nm).Parent.Name '****Error is occurring here
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("outputSheet").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = nm.Name
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("outputSheet").Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = nm.RefersToRange.Address(False, False)
    i = i + 1
Next
   
wkb.Close savechanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You are expecting some single sheet's `Range` to be able to find all [global names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2176154/11683). It won't. If you need the name of the worksheet a range refers to, you already have it at `nm.RefersToRange.Parent.Name`.

Comment: @Gserg Should I instead loop through each sheet in the specified workbook, and then look for all names?

Comment: Then you will fail on all sheets instead of on one sheet. You are already using `nm.RefersToRange`, just use it more.

Comment: Try `nm.RefersToRange.Parent.Name` instead of `Range(nm).Parent.Name`. Nevertheless with this for-loop you only retrieve the workbook-level-names. To retrieve *worksheet*-level-names you will have to use two for-loops: `for each ws in wkb.worksheets` and then `for each nm in ws.names`

Comment: @Ike adding in `Dim ws as Worksheet`, the higher level loop, and `nm.RefersToRange.Parent.Name`. I had to use `nm.Parent.Name` to stop a Application-defined or object-defined error. But now it's only looping through whatever sheet is selected in the specified workbook.

Comment: Problem might be that you have `Names` that are not `Named Ranges` at all. E.g. I can declare a `Name` "Test" and have it refer to `=1` (i.e. just a constant). When you meet this particular `Name` inside your loop, you'll get the error specified as well at `Range(nm.Name).Parent.Name`. Maybe loop through your names with just `Debug.Print (nm.Name & ": " & nm.RefersTo)` and check output.

Comment: @ouroboros1 That was it, with some solver values being constants. Any why it's only looping through one sheet? Do I need to be explicit to begin on sheet 1, and loop until the final sheet?

Comment: Not sure. Suppose I have the following names: `NamedRange`, ref `=Sheet1!A2:A4` (global scope), another `NamedRange`, ref `=Sheet2!A2:A4` (now local scope: "Sheet2"), and `NameConstant`, ref `=1`. If now I use your initial loop, but with `On Error Resume Next` in front, I just get what I would expect: `[empty] | NameConstant | [empty], Sheet2 | Sheet2!NamedRange | A2:A4, Sheet1 | NamedRange | A2:A4`