Range Property Not Returning Correct Value for Relative Named Range in VBA Excel 365
I've named a Range as ID and set its address as =Materiais!$B3. it is fixed for column but for the row, it will depend on the ActivateCell current position.
when I click on the G8 cell, for instance, the Name Manager identifies the correct cell value, as you can see on the image below. in this case, the letter e.
when I try to get this value via VBA code, it doesn't bring any value.
this is the VBA code that I'm using:
Sub ValorRange()
    MsgBox Range("Materiais!ID").Value
End Sub

it was supposed to bring the letter e, as Name Manager does.
I think it was not happening on Excel 2010 but I cannot do this test now. I'm using Excel 365 version.
thanks in advance.

I'd appreciate your help.
GSerg, ws.Range("ID") returns B1 cell value, as you can see below:


Did you put Sub ValorRange() in a worksheet that is not Materials? Then it won't work. Application.Range("Materiais!ID") will find your range from any sheet, Worksheet.Range("Materiais!ID") will not.

@DecimalTurn I don't get any error. I get B1 cell value.

@GSerg Sub ValorRange() is in a general module. I changed my code to Application.Range("Materiais!ID") but, it didn't work anyway. it is taking the value from B1 cell.

This new code should work. I added 'rngLimit' and VBA's Intersec method to check if 'rng' is contained in 'rngLimit'.
Sub ValorRange()

    Dim ws As Worksheet                     ' Worksheet object
    Dim rng As Range                        ' Range object
    Dim rngLimit As Range                   ' Range object
    Set ws = Sheets("Materiais")            ' Sets ws to worsheet
    Set rng = ws.Names("ID").RefersToRange  ' Gets range referenced by named cell
    Set rngLimit = ws.Range("B3:B100")      ' Gets limited range
    
    ' If intersection between rng and B3:B100 exists, shows rng value
    If Not Intersect(rng, rngLimit) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox rng.Value
    Else
        ' Set default value or throws an error
        MsgBox "Error or default value"
    End If

End Sub

In a more generic version, you can use 'ws', 'rng' and 'rngLimit' as parameters of 'ValorRange' function.

There is rarely a need to use Names specifically. If you have a named range on that sheet with the scope of workbook, it won't find it.

@GSerg it worked perfectly! thanks a lot! but why should it be this way? can you explain me that? if I'm not wrong, I would do exactly the ways that I was doing but in Excel 2010 and it worked. I never did this way before.

@AlexBoorjs https://stackoverflow.com/q/2175962/11683. You don't have to do it this way specifically, you can do ws.Range("ID").

@GSerg ws.Range("ID") returns B1 cell value. it doesn't work. can I delimit Range("Materiais!ID") within the cells from B3 to B100, for instance? because =Materiais!$B3 address allows me to get the column name, if ActiveCell is in row 2.

@AlexBoorjs It cannot return B1 according to what you have shown. I'm not sure how you know it returns B1 either because it's empty. You have two names called ID, both scoped to sheets - one to Materiais, one to Estoque. When you ask Sheets("Materiais") to resolve Range("ID"), it will give you the cell B8.

@GSerg as you can see at the image that I've added on top, Range("Materiais!ID") returns xxx, the value that I've put in cell B1 in order to do the test. but ws.Names("ID").RefersToRange.Value returns the letter e, as expected.

@AlexBoorjs Nelson's answer is correct, but it's incomplete since it doesn't explain why Range doesn't work. I've provided an answer to clarify why this happens.

@DecimalTurn you are right! Nelson's solution works perfectly. that's how I'll do from now on.

I try to convince myself that I know how ranges work in Excel-VBA, but this is actually something I had not encountered before. What you have here is indeed a relative named range which will update based on the active cell when you use it inside an Excel formula.
For the reason that they change based on the active cell, you should probably avoid using them inside VBA code since it could introduce unpredictability in the behavior of your code or force you to change the selected cell multiple times to make your calculations (obligatory mention of How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA).
Your named range is defined as RC2 in R1C1 notation and $B1 in A1 notation (with respect to cell A1). To evaluate this value, Excel needs a starting cell to convert the relative position into an absolute position. However, the VBA Range method doesn't use the active cell, it always uses A1 which is why you always get the value in B1 when using the Range method.
Nelson's answer works because it makes use of RefersToRange instead which does pass the active cell along to calulate the position on the sheet. This is why it works the way you are used to when using the named range inside a cell.
